# reverse/httpresponseredirect doesn't work in django

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I'm making a multiple page form, where every single page will save data in different tables. Now, when I submit the form, my view should HttpResponseRedirect to a reversed url. But that's exactly what is not going on. The fact is that `return HttpResponse(reverse('url')` prints the right url, but `HttpResponseRedirect` doesnt redirect to the reversed url.

This is the code:

```
def get_form_naw(request, form_id, filterid, project_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OpnameNawForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form_id = int(form_id) + 1
            url = reverse('opname:get_form', kwargs={'form_id': form_id, 'filterid': filterid, 'project_id': project_id})
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = OpnameNawForm()
    return render(request, 'opname/home.html', {'form': form})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^formulier/step/(?P<filterid>[^/?]+)/(?P<form_id>[^/?]+)/(?P<project_id>[^/?]+)/$', views.get_form, name='get_form'),
```

Comment: did you try `redirect(url)`?? `from django.shortcuts import redirect` ..... what error are you getting??

Comment: I am not getting an error, just a blank page. Redirect does the same thing. Im submitting the form, then leaves a blank page, not the new page.

Comment: can you show the `get_form` view??

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your url, maybe somewhat like this, (assuming the ids are integers),

```
url(r'^formulier/step/(?P<filterid>[\d]+)/(?P<form_id>[\d]+)/(?P<project_id>[\d]+)/$', views.get_form, name='get_form')
```